# rsync from groovy: "-e" arg causing "unknown remote arg" error

Tags: bash, groovy, rsync

There's no shortage of questions regarding rsync invocation, but I don't see anything helpful in tens that I've read, so this is the command I'm struggling with:

```
$ rsync -av -e 'ssh -i key.id_dsa -l root' root@server:/dir/file /tmp/file
```

It works from bash. I invoke it from Groovy code using the `String.execute()` method and it fails as follows:

```
command exit code: 1
rsync command output:

rsync command error output:
Unexpected remote arg: root@server:/dir/file
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.0]
```

Apparently, the `-e` switch and its value is the problem: commands such as `rsync -av -r --progress root@server:/dir/file /tmp/file` works flawlessly.

Question 0: why is the `-e` parameter special?

Question 1: how do I make it work?

Comment: can you try:  `["bash", "-c", "rsync -av -e 'ssh -i key.id_dsa -l root' root@server:/dir/file /tmp/file"].execute()`?

Comment: @tim_yates can you please make your comment an answer, so that I can upvote it and accept it? (-; Thanks, this is a really nice present you gave me on an otherwise very difficult day.

Comment: BTW, any idea why the '-e' switch seems to be special? Use of quotes for the specified argument?

Comment: Glad to help...  Not sure, I'm _guessing_ that bash does something to expand up that argument, or the rsync call does something to the owning shell which fails if it's not run under bash...  But that's a total guess...  Without the List form of execute, some things fail, and some pass, and it's hard to call which will fail

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the `-e` switch is something fancy required by the bash shell...  So to invoke the command with the bash shell behind it, you'd need to use the `List` form of `execute` like so:

```
["bash", "-c", "rsync -av -e 'ssh -i key.id_dsa -l root' root@server:/dir/file /tmp/file"].execute()
```

And that should get it running (I invariably use this form, as it always seems to be less error-prone than the `String.execute()` form)

Comment: This issue is not because of the `-e` but the quote after that. Quotes are interpreted by bash, and `Runtime.exec` just split the arguments between spaces and ignore the quotes.